# PHPWord categories on axis Y

Tags: php, charts, phpword

I would like to create bar chart using PHPWord 0.15 (this library can't be change).

I want to receive result similar to chart below:
[image]

How can I add category name on axis Y ?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Can you please share your code?

Comment: @DaFois basically code is too heavy to share here.
This is basically conceptual issue, because Chart class not support strings on axis Y.

i've try to add chart in various combination of this code
`$chart = $section->addChart($type, $categories, $values)`

But even when values are correcty added, and axis X is ok, on Axis Y values are read from array keys. When I force text there all categories are read as `1`.

I need only a concept or simple solution which show me a direction